# Why does mobile first responsive design tend to not use max-width queries alongside the min-width queries?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

First off, I understand the basic principles behind mobile first responsive web design, and totally agree with them. But one thing I don't understand:

In my experience, not *all* styles for small screens can be used for the larger version of a website. For example, usually smaller versions tend to have larger clickable areas, [hamburger navigation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/32877/what-is-this-side-menu-called-that-can-be-found-in-many-multi-touch-apps-and-wh), etc. So I sometimes have to override these specific styles, aside from just progressively enhancing the base styles.

So I was wondering: why is max-width rarely mentioned (or used) in the context of mobile-first responsive web design? Because it looks like it could be used together with min-width to isolate styles for smaller screens that are not useful for larger screens, and would thus prevent unnecessary duplication of code.

---

A quote which mentions min-width as typically mobile-first, but not max-width:

> With that in mind, which media query best fits with the “mobile first” methodology?
>   Assuming we want to build a mobile / small screen layout, and then
>   expand on the styling for larger browsers, it’d be min-width ...
>   The alternative is styling the site for a desktop browser, using
>   max-width queries instead to apply new CSS as device width decreases.
>   But that’s contrary to the “mobile first” approach

*from: http://petegale.com/blog/css-media-queries-min-width-vs-max-width/*

---

EDIT: So to be more specific: I was wondering if there is a reason to exclude max-width from a mobile-first responsive design (as it seems like it can be useful for writing your css as DRY as possible, as some styles for small screens will not be used for bigger screens).

Comment: I would say that the people writing the articles that you are reading simply did not think they needed them. There's nothing stopping you from using them though.. It's not like "mobile first" is a strict set of rules where people will find you and beat you if you don't follow them haha. I personally design desktop downwards partly because of what you are saying. (also because I tend to design websites that I would prefer people to view on a desktop display)

Comment: @BlakeMann, haha yeah of course I understand that I can adapt the rules. It's just that I was wondering what the reason was for the strict association between mobile first and min-width, and whether there was a reason for max-width not being mentioned as a useful tool as well.

Comment: By the way, I understand that min-width is associated with mobile-first RWD because of the progressive enhancement (and thus building upon the base styles, instead of stripping them away with max-width). I was just wondering if there are reasons not to use it for the goals I mentioned in the question, aside from progressive enhancement.

Comment: Look, I understand why you asked the question, but http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*I'm not sure if this post is a comment or an answer, but I completely agree that `max-width` is too often ignored or even looked down upon and would like to present my two cents on the topic.*

For most media queries, `min-width` is without a doubt the best approach. A common scenario is `float`, where you rarely want floated elements on a slim screen but still want them to float on larger screens, so you simply add the `float` through a `min-width` media query.

### Generalized, the reasoning is that *it's better to add something once it's needed rather than removing it when it's not.*

Since you almost always add more CSS to larger screens rather than vice-versa, it makes sense people limit themselves to `min-width` media queries.

But what about the scenarios when you actually *do* add CSS that's exclusive to the smaller screen?

Perhaps you want to replace text with an icon and have to do it through pseudo elements, perhaps you're doing layout changes with CSS for small screens. Perhaps you need to change some colors or add a `margin`/`padding` to the smaller screen.

It doesn't really matter, the point is that sometimes you want to add something to a smaller screen that's not supposed to be there on the larger screen. So, following the previously stated reasoning, in those scenarios it makes sense to use `max-width` instead of `min-width`.

Comment: I think this is the best explained answer, especially the point about it being better to add something when needed rather than removing. Basically, the ideal goal when developing a site should be to never override a style. If you plan your styles in such a way that the ones that will only apply to small screens go in `min-width`, and the ones that only apply to large screens go in `max-width`, you will have some pretty clean styles. Can this be difficult to plan, and more work than it's worth? Absolutely.. but it's always a good goal to strive towards.

Comment: @BlakeMann, also, you could define basic styles and then build upon them with min-width. And then any styles (like styles for small screens that do not apply to large screens) can be isolated by combining a min-width with a max-width media query (`(min-width:x) and (max-width:y)`). That's not difficult to plan, and actually simpler than only using min-width, since you don't have to override anything anymore, you can just isolate it.

Answer (score 3):

Mobile first responsive design is a philosophy, an idea, a goal. How you achieve that goal is open for interpretation.

The use of one or the other technique just has more to do with complexity. In the end you want to use a 'system' which is understandable. The more parameters you use in the design of your system the harder debugging becomes.

There is no real difference between using max-width and min-width queries, besides the obvious different strains of thought they require. Using just one or the other is simply a choice to [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) ;)

Nobody is forcing you to do the same, but I would also advice you to KISS.

Ofcourse, if you need it, add it, but some hesistation is never bad. Take the time to assess your options and see what keeps things low on the complexity scale, it's usually the better option.

Comment: I agree. That's also exactly the reason for my asking about max-width. Because it just feels redundant to have to nullify small screen styles for the larger layouts, when a simple and (min-device-width : x) and (max-device-width : x) could isolate them. I will of course still stick to a basic min-width based design for all other cases.

Answer (score 2):

max-width is not rarely mentioned and is highly used for developing responsive designs for handheld devices. I do prefer to use max-device-width more frequently. There is no generalization over the understanding to use max-width rarely.

You can check various media-queries (frequently used) for various mobile devices over here: http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/

For iPhone: http://www.stephentgilbert.com/mediaqueries/

To be more sure about my designs, I do use media-type as handheld more occasionally.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The sources you mentioned do seem to approach responsive design in a more old fashioned way though (fixed widths based on device resolution, and not based on the points where the design breaks). Let me ask my question more specifically: I was wondering what the reason was for the strict association between mobile first and min-width, and whether there is a reason for excluding max-width from a mobile first responsive design (as it seems like it can be useful for writing your css as DRY as possible as some styles will not be used for desktops).

Answer (score 0):

As a web developer with 20+ years of experience, I will tell you why I dislike max-width.  Number one answer, it can cause irritating problems with fractional pixel width displays.  Consider this media query:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-md-50 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-md-50 {
    width: 50%;
  ]
}
```

At first, this looks harmless.  But it is not correctly written and I will tell you why.  Set your browser's zoom to an odd factor like 125% and resize and you will see that a screen can have fractional width pixels.  You can achieve a screen width of 767.2px for example, and your UI is going to be broken, because you're now in between the 2 breakpoints that were designed, in a "breakpoint hole".  And it is usually challenging to debug and fix this type of issue.

If you start clean, and use a mobile-first approach, you're going to sidestep this entire class of problems.  Here's how to achieve the same effect:

```
.col-md-50 {
  width: 100%
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-md-50 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

This is not only simpler, it will never have an incorrect display.  Later, if you add another breakpoint, the browser will always pick the highest one, so you don't have a specificity conflict with lower ones that match, so you do not need a min-width and max-width, if your breakpoints are properly all layered with min-width.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-md-50 {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

This will work as expected in every browser, overriding the lower resolution breakpoints.  So we get a default width for this class of 100% on mobile, switch to 2-up 50% width on medium, and for anything larger than 1200px, it will be a 4-up 25% width.

CSS can be challenging to maintain.  By taking a clean, mobile-first approach, we can have an easier way to reason about which code is overriding which, at any given resolution.